# Does the cockpit have an alarm to warn about fuel leakage?

Tags: cockpit, fuel-tanks

Is there any indication to the crew of the aircraft about any potential leakage of fuel from any part of the plane?

Comment: There is a fuel gage that you should keep an eye on.

Comment: I recall that the flight computer on Airbus / Boeing computes the fuel quantity that *should* be using engine fuel flow. If the calculated fuel and actual fuel differs too much, it will show an amber alert.

Comment: On every light aircraft I know of the fuel leak detectors are the pilots' eyes and nose. Fuel stinks, even a small leak can make things very unpleasant in the cockpit (trust me from first hand experience). A loose fuel cap can empty a tank in minutes due to suction, and that's visible to the pilot. Fuel dripping from the airplane is another visible clue.

Comment: @GdD That's true in many cases, but at night or in IMC you probably won't be able to see fuel leaking. Of course your nose should still work :-)

Comment: My nose seems to work at night, YMMV though ;)

Comment: @kevin: Does the avionics knows what is the actual fuel quantity inside the tanks, or just how much is going to the engines (actual fuel flow rate)? Because the actual fuel flow rate will not be impacted by a leak upstream the FF metering unit, at least not before the tanks are empty...

Comment: @mins, it knows both, but if the leak is near the engine comparing these still might not detect it, so in the wake of [Air Transat 236](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Transat_Flight_236) incident comparison against flight _plan_ was added.

Comment: @JanHudec: Thanks for the info, and the reference to the Transat 236 which I didn't know. Checking in the A320 FCOM, I actually found this: "*The FOI system installed on Airbus aircraft use probes to measure the quantity of fuel in the different fuel tanks. Each FOI probe consists of two fixed concentric tubes which form the plates of a capacitor.*". So your comment seems to be an answer for Airbus a/c.

Comment: As this question stands, I think that it is too broad, because there are many different kinds of airplanes with different capabilities, and the answer will be different for many of them.  Please narrow the scope down to a specific type or group of aircraft so that it can be answered.

Comment: Gimly glider was not caused by fuel leakage. The cause was mistake between metric and imperical unit used.

Comment: Does the ground crew get the alarm of low fuel too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical trainer aircraft (in this case, a C172), you have an annunciator panel that includes a "Low Fuel" light:

[image: CESSNA 172]

These lights only come on when fuel is low if the lights are functioning properly. This panel is located prominently, and is easy to notice. This is only one aircraft, but when you consider it is an entry level aircraft that is less sophisticated, it gives a baseline idea of what you could expect to see.

Also, there are fuel gauges displayed with all engine instruments that will indicate accordingly. While this isn't a leak detector, pilots are trained to monitor all instruments regularly and cross check the values - which is how a leak is identified in aircraft with low amounts of technology.

It is worth noting that checking the "LOW FUEL" annunciator is off is a regular checklist item that occurs before you start your actual flight.

As GdD mentions in the comments - you are taught not to rely on any one instrument indication, and panel lights are no exception.

Comment: What typical trainer are you talking about? I've been in 1 light aircraft which had a low fuel enunciator, and I was told not to depend on it!

Comment: Gah - I put the aircraft type as part of the image description - I'll add it to the answer itself.

Comment: While this indicates you get short of fuel, this doesn't indicate if a leak is currently occurring.

Comment: @mins - you are correct. I suppose I was assuming that the pilot would interpret the indications of the fuel level indicators (including the panel light) to recognize a leak.

Comment: Yes, but this information cannot help act before the tanks are low, which would be possible if a leak alarm existed.

Comment: I agree with @mins, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no special indicator or warning about a fuel leak because it would be difficult to automatically detect a fuel leak with any certainty (fuel flow sensors are not super accurate, nor are fuel quantity sensors).

Pilots of small, single tank airplanes must rely on reading the fuel quantity indicators periodically and "knowing" how much fuel should be left and how much is actually left. Big discrepancies indicate a possible fuel leak.

Pilots of bigger, multi-tank airplanes check for (and, on more sophisticated airplanes, are warned about) fuel imbalances between tanks. A fuel imbalance again, indicates a fuel leak as it is very very unlikely that the same quantity has leaked from both tanks.

You can find further info about fuel leak detection on Airbus airplanes [here](http://www.oaviao.com/pesquisa_codigo_empresas/manuais_voo/performance_airbus/fuel_leaks.html).